# String.indexOf() throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string

In the below program, I have to first read a file and then write it. In the run configurations I provided the path of the file but when I run the program then it gives error:      `String index out of range: -1`. ? Please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

String fileName = args[0];
    Scanner filescan;//to read the file
    filescan=new Scanner(new File(fileName));//read the whole file

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName.subSequence(0,fileName.indexOf(".uniqe.ICext"))+".uniqe.Mpwm");
    BufferedWriter mpwm = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

Comment: Does the filename contain `.unique.ICext`?

Comment: Filename is sequences.txt

Comment: then what exactly are you trying to do in the 7th line?

Comment: Thank you. I just changed the extension of my file to .unique.ICext and output file was generated.

Answer (score 1):

you should add validations before use substring. otherwise it will eventually throw an Exception

```
int i= fileName.indexOf(".uniqe.ICext");
if(i<0)
    //file name can't substring or handle exception
else
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName.subSequence(0,i)+".uniqe.Mpwm");
```